# Mathematica wrongly displays rows instead of columns

Tags: display

I want to perform some operations with certain column but when I tried to display the first column as it is shown in attached picture 1 (in some reference on web) of the table but Mathematica displayed the first row instead
my code is in second picture.
Can anyone please explain and tell me how to fix it? 
Thank you very much!
[image: First correct picture]

[image: Second wrong picture]

Comment: Notice the original example does not involve `MatrixForm` in the definition of `data`. You've added one level to your structure, please see linked topics.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thanks for help.